# Deleting Entity in Entity Model gives Foreign Key errors

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Deleting Entity in Entity Model gives Foreign Key errors

Error   92  Error 3013: Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 5023, 5183, 5507: Missing table mapping: Foreign key constraint 'FK_TableName' from table TableName(ID) to table Other_TableName (ID): no mapping specified for the table TableName
    C:\MyDirector\MyModel.edmx  5024    15  MyNamespace

any idea how i get rid of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to edit the edmx file in notepad and remove every Association and AssociationSet where i found 'FK_TableName'

Answer (score 0):

for me this happened when I changed foreign key column types from string to int; after doing "update model from database", he updated the rest but the constraints remained to be strings. I opened the EDMX file in notepad++ and changed the foreign key constraint type from string to the proper type, then everything worked again.